# Twitter boostrap button groups using btn-primary

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to define a `btn-group` (`buttons-radio` mode, that is, radio style), as explained [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups), but instead of using the the `active` class for the selected button, I would like to use `btn-primary`, so that the selected button is more clearly visible.

My question is: do I need to implement custom javascript/jQuery to achieve this, or can I somehow tell bootstrap to use `btn-primary` instead of `active` for selected button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is modify the js library.
Change the below code (please find them in bootstrap-button.js):

```
  Button.prototype.toggle = function () {
    var $parent = this.$element.parent('[data-toggle="buttons-radio"]')

    $parent && $parent
      .find('.active')
      .removeClass('active')

    this.$element.toggleClass('active')
  }
```

to be the following:

```
  Button.prototype.toggle = function () {
    var $parent = this.$element.parent('[data-toggle="buttons-radio"]')

    $parent && $parent
      .find('.btn-primary')
      .removeClass('btn-primary')

    this.$element.toggleClass('btn-primary')
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend to change any of bootstrap JS. It's better to create custom onclick event and "recycle" bootstrap code.

In my case I had HTML like:

```
<div id="bar" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success active">First</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large">Second</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large">Third</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
I've come how to override toggle function

```
$.fn.button.Constructor.prototype.oldtoggle = $.fn.button.Constructor.prototype.toggle
$.fn.button.Constructor.prototype.toggle = function(){
    var $parent = this.$element.parent('[data-toggle="buttons-radio"]')

    $parent && $parent
      .find('.btn-success')
      .removeClass('btn-success')

    this.$element.toggleClass('btn-success')
    this.oldtoggle()
}
```

This allows you to style only the btn-groups you want.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with darkless, don't modify the existing javascript.

I did something along the lines of:

HTML:

```
<div class="my-parent-row">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" data-selected-class="btn-success">
        <button class="btn btn-success active">First option</button>
        <button class="btn">Other option</button>                
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".my-parent-row .btn-group .btn").on("click", function () {
    var selectedClass = $(this).parent().data("selected-class");
    $(this).siblings("." + selectedClass).removeClass(selectedClass);
    $(this).addClass(selectedClass);
});
```

Comment: Well, I thought that "on click" would be sufficient. But it isn't. If you have to use methods for toggling the button in JS ($('#button').toggle()), the "on click" trigger won't fire. So that's why I came with overriding the method.

Comment: Good catch, in my case I won't be using the `.toggle()` so I don't need to worry about that, but it's good to remember.